# Photoshop Guides for widescreen web designs

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

Does anybody know what the guides should be set at get a basic viewport for the typical 13" widscreen laptop?

Anybody know of a template of sorts that can assist in this matter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your web site only targeting only users that browser full screen and only own 13" wide screen laptop computers? If so, it's a valid question. But consider the range of devices and screens and browsers your site users might be viewing your site with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will vary with the make and model of a specific laptop but at 13" and widescreen: either 1366x768 or 1280x800 pixels is a pretty safe bet for the screen res. taking the smallest dimension of both gives a likely 1280x768

- take approx 120-150px off the vertical height (browser/OS chrome)
- take approx 20px off the horizontal width (scroll bar)

this leaves **approx 1260x600 px for a *maximised* window.**

you should make sure your webdesign works at a number of different resolutions though. It is common for a user to run their web browser at less than full screen, and your design should be fluid to accomodate this.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider making your left and right margins elastic so it can adjust to the various makes / models / users out there. I will typically create a div  that's less than 800 px wide and center it in the body. The content goes in there and it stays a consistent width no matter how wide they make the browser window. It makes life a lot easier when figuring out page layout and flow.